# DRF: How to password protect the DefaultRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How would you go about protecting `DefaultRouter()` so the user can not view API Root unless they are logged in?

```
class OrderViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated)
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'orders', views.OrderViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

project.urls.py

```
# API
url(r'^api/', include(api_urls)),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add default permission classes in your settings.py file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Comment: I updated the original question with more detail. After adding `DEFAUL_PERMISSION_CLASSES` API Root is still visible when I visit 127.0.0.1:8000/api/

Comment: This worked for me! 

For those using DRF with JWT, make sure to specify this before the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`:

```REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}
```